# How can I lock(freeze) a div into a jquery application?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a jquery application, and I want to add a watermark (a small picture in the top-left corner) to it for the free version. I'm struggling to make as hard as possible for the users to remove it using javascript. I'm loading that image into a div and position it with a high value for it's z-index property, so it's always on top.

So I've came up with this solution, but it isn't strong enough:

- a timer that adds the watermark periodicaly if it has been reemoved (doesn't works if the user makes it's own timer that removes the watermark periodicaly).

Do you have any other ideeas? But not something very hard to code.

Thanks.

Comment: Just give up - it cannot be done. The user can override whatever you do.

Comment: I agree with @Saintedlama. I was once tasked with devising such a scheme, and we came up with something in the end but I felt it was a waste. I must've convinced the boss, because after coming up with the solution we abandoned it. If you really want/need a watermark, just do it in a simple way. The people who respect your wishes will leave it, and the ones who don't were never going to anyhow.

Comment: I'm not trying the impossible, I'm just trying to give the user some headache if he wants to remove that watermark. I know that a good javascript coder will always find a way to hack the product.

Answer (score 6):

I'd hack your solution by simply blocking the image with some ad blocking tool in my browser :)

Before you invest a lot of energy in a hack safe watermark solution you could answer yourself some questions:

- What percentage of your user base will use some js hacks and ad block solutions to block your watermark?
- How much time must a user invest to remove your watermark?
- Does this pay of for you to invest effort x to realize a hack safe solution compared to  the users that use some js hack trick?
- Is removing your the "free" watermark the only value add that users gain if they pay for the "non free" product?
- Will this value be attractive for users to pay for the "non free" product?

From my experience the time/cost invested for solutions to block some user hacks is better invested in implementing some value adding features for the "non free" product.

Comment: I agree, Jquery libs are normally open sourced. Its up to you to create some form of license and 'trust' the user. For example, telerik asp.net mvc controls.

Comment: If you block the images you would block one of the functionalities of the product (image rotator). The watermark image is hardcoded using a base64 string. I specified in the question's text "Do you have any other ideeas? But not something very hard to code.". I'm trying not to invest to much into this, but not to make something very easy for the users either.

Comment: The final code will be obfuscated, so it will make it a little harder for the user to interact with it.